# Trying to install cp-helm-charts: Settings are ignored

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kubernetes-helm, confluent-platform

I am trying to install [cp-helm-charts](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts).

I want to be able to access the topology from outside.

So I did:

```
helm install --set external.enabled=true confluentinc/cp-helm-charts
```

But a `kubectl get services` still tells me:

```
wishful-newt-cp-kafka                ClusterIP   10.106.112.201   <none>        9092/TCP            115s
wishful-newt-cp-kafka-connect        ClusterIP   10.104.46.32     <none>        8083/TCP            115s
wishful-newt-cp-kafka-headless       ClusterIP   None             <none>        9092/TCP            115s
wishful-newt-cp-kafka-rest           ClusterIP   10.105.4.206     <none>        8082/TCP            115s
wishful-newt-cp-ksql-server          ClusterIP   10.104.90.228    <none>        8088/TCP            115s
wishful-newt-cp-schema-registry      ClusterIP   10.103.12.45     <none>        8081/TCP            115s
wishful-newt-cp-zookeeper            ClusterIP   10.101.18.171    <none>        2181/TCP            115s
wishful-newt-cp-zookeeper-headless   ClusterIP   None             <none>        2888/TCP,3888/TCP   115s
```

Any ideas what I might be missing?

Comment: Could you please provide your Helm and Kubernetes versions? And also your Helm install logs?

Answer (score 3):

The `external.enable` value is specific for some sub-charts. When specifying values from the parent, you need to prefix the sub-chart name that you are changing the config for. For example:

Setting external access for [KSQL](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/tree/master/charts/cp-ksql-server#external-access):

`helm install --set=cp-ksql-server.external.enabled=true confluentinc/cp-helm-charts`

Setting external access for [Kafka Rest](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/tree/master/charts/cp-kafka-rest#external-access):

`helm install --set=cp-kafka-rest.external.enabled=true confluentinc/cp-helm-charts`

---

If your intention is to set external access to [Kafka](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/blob/master/charts/cp-kafka/README.md#external-access), you should use:

`helm install --set=cp-kafka.nodeport.enabled=true confluentinc/cp-helm-charts`